# JSON Web Encryption (JWE) Key Wrapping Fundamentals - How To Encrypt Content Encryption Key?

Tags: rsa, pkcs1, key-wrap, jwt, jwe

The [JSON Web Encryption RFC 7516](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7516#section-5.1) says:

> Encrypt the CEK with the recipient's public key using the
> RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 [or RSAES-OAEP] algorithm to produce the JWE
> Encrypted Key.

Assuming a client/server architecture here where the server generates JWE tokens, does this mean that the client must initiate the JWA creation process by creating a public/private key pair and sending the public key to the server? This seems unusual as the general rule of thumb is that the private key encrypts while the public key decrypts?

Can someone help me understand the basic flow for JWA with Key Agreement & Key Wrapping?